# How to get android app to top of search result in play store similar to uber

Tags: android, google-play

Can anyone explain how to get my android application on play store search results similar to uber. (as shown in image below)[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your application on top.There are many different factors by which you can bring your app to top:-
1)choose a very unique name for your app.
2)If the app has just been launched and has less than 10 downloads then the google 
 play store doesn't show it to users(try searching with package name).
3)Doing some marketing for your app will surely help.